# jquery type error = 0, function

Tags: jquery, function, typeerror

i've got a function inside my `document.ready`

```
  function changeLabel (labelname, newValue) {
    if ($(labelname).html().indexOf("span class") > -1) {
        $(labelname).html("<span class='error'>" + newValue + "</span>");
    } else {
        $(labelname).html(newValue);
    }
  }
```

but now i get an errormessage in my firebug:

`TypeError: $(labelname).html()` is `null`

i don't really understand what's the problem, using the function would be like this:

```
changeLabel ("#raffle label[for='first_name']",'Firstname *:');
```

Comment: What happens when you directly execute '$("#raffle label[for='first_name']").html().indexOf("span class")' ?

Comment: I would say that your selector if not finding a match. Perhaps post the relevant HTML code too

Comment: musefan you are so right, stupid from me, i just added ...if ($('#raffle').length > 0 ) {... and now it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

change the selector to `'label[for="first_name"]','#raffle'` this changes the location of where to look for your label. If you're looking for labels only in `#raffle` replace your selector to something like this.

```
$(labelname,'#raffle').html();

changeLabel('label[for="first_name"]','new value');
```

Not sure if it'll solve the problem. But may do as you're selector is possibly incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

using jquery `index()`..
try this

```
if ($(labelname).index($("span.error")) > -1) {
    $(labelname).html("<span class='error'>" + newValue + "</span>");
} else {
    $(labelname).html(newValue);
}
```